# How to implement a separate android project on the gradle's dependencies, without modifying the path or url

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have this scenario in Gradle (build.gradle)

```
implementation ("br.com.mycompany.feature:feature:$mycompanyFeatureVersion") {
               transitive = true 
               exclude group: 'br.com.mycompany', module: 'comons'
}
```

I need to point the path of the "Feature" in my dependencies, I'm working on on my machine, but I can't change $mycompanyFeatureVersion, How can I do this?
I can't point the path of the .jar directly, it's called a very bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Files> New> Module

It is necessary to create a new module (which is a folder), you must insert the connector project (project you want to insert) in this module-folder, and insert the plugins in the build.gradle of the connector project:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

The "library" is to transform the apk into a library
and "maven-publish" is so that the folder can be inserted as a dependency.

Then insert in the dependency (build.gradle) with the address of the module
implementation ("us.com.company.project: modulename: $ variableifisneeded)

That's how I solved it after putting the question on the stack